# How do I repeat background of header image when right and left side are different?

Tags: html, css

here is a background image for a header I want to repeat[image]

how do I repeat the image horizontaly because the left and right are not the same?

Comment: Is that 'white' area actually transparent?

Comment: Unclear what effect you are seeking, can you post an image?

Comment: @Paulie_D either or...I would most likely make it white...but still how would this work since both sides are not the same

Comment: @JoshKG can you really not see the posted image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to make the image fit a variable width, you need to set a part that needs to repeat. There is no way of doing this with one image, since you can't mirror the image.

You will need to manually mirror the image. An example could be:

Html:

```
<div class="left-image side"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right-image side"></div>
```

The CSS would be something like:

```
.side {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: *height of the image*;
    width: *width of the image*;
}

.left-image {
    background: url('*link to left image*') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    left: 0;
}

.right-image {
    right: 0;
    background: url('*link to right image*') no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
}

.center {
    height: *height of lowest part, or height of image*;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(*url of image*) repeat-x 0 0 transparent;
    /* or */
    background: *color*;
}
```

The center could either be a repeating image, or just the background color in width the height of your image. This depends on the image you're using.

I hope this helps.

Comment: so you would instead have 2 images instead of the one...but why is the repeat set to no repeat?

Comment: I edited my code a bit. You don't use repeat, because you can't repeat an image that differs on either side. They don't repeat well. That is why you repeat the .center (as now visible, since my edit). I hope that makes sense. If not, I'd be happy to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an extra image, the smallest part and declare both images in your background css 
background:url(xxx.jpg),url(yy.gif)
or cut the image at the angle and just repeat the smaller image.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have the black portion through out then,
You cant repeat this image, as this will not be giving good effect, try just cutting a small part of it and repeat that, it will distribute itself evenly.

Answer (score 0):

Just position the image to the right and set a bg color the same color as the image.

NB...will not work with transparent image.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VN6PN/)**

```
header {
    height:96px;
    background-color:black; /* or whatever color of image is */
    background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF6ey.png);
    background-position:top right;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```